# oauth_signature generation for Google API

Tags: php, oauth, google-api

I am trying to get the contacts of user for my website, but I am not able to get a token from google because i am getting invalid oauth signature error.

How to generate an oauth signature in PHP for google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I did for getting data from google analytics

```
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin');
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
  $data = array(
    'accountType' => 'GOOGLE',
    'Email' => $email, //your google email
    'Passwd' => $password, //your google pass
    'service' => 'analytics',
    'source' => 'curl-accountFeed-v2'
    );
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
  $response = curl_exec($curl);
  $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  if ($info['http_code'] == 200) {
   if ($response) {
     preg_match('/Auth=(.*)/', $response, $matches);
     if (isset($matches[1])) {
       $auth_code = $matches[1];
     }
   }
  }
```

Comment: Hey, I think its for loging in our out , but, i need to import contact of the users taking their permission using oauth signature. Please comment if i am wrong